# is there a way to use numpy.where() for a raster data with NaN values as no-data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nan, rasterio

I have a raster data that includes NaN values as no-data. I want to calculate new raster from it like if raster==0 do statement1, if raster==1 do statement2, if raster between 0 and 1 do statement3, otherwise don't change the value. how can I do this using numpy.where() function?

here is my code:

```
import os
import rasterio
from rasterio import plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

os.listdir('../NDVI_output')

ndvi1 = rasterio.open("../NDVI_output/NDVI.tiff")

min_value = ndvi_s = np.nanmin(ndvi) #NDVI of Bare soil
max_value = ndvi_v = np.nanmax(ndvi) #NDVI of full vegetation cover

fvc = (ndvi-ndvi_s)/(ndvi_v-ndvi_s) #fvc: Fractional Vegetation Cover

band4 = rasterio.open('../TOAreflectance_output/TOAref_B4.tiff')
toaRef_red = band4.read(1).astype('float64')
emiss = np.where((fvc == 1.).any(), 0.99,
                 (np.where((fvc == 0.).any(), 0.979-0.046*toaRef_red,
                           (np.where((0.<fvc<1.).any(), 0.971*(1-fvc)+0.987*fvc, fvc)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `raster` is an array,

- `raster == x` gives a boolean mask, with the same shape as `raster`, indicating which elements (in your case pixels) of `raster` are equal to `x`
- `np.where(arr)` gives the indices of elements of the array `arr` that evaluates to true. `np.where(raster == x)`, therefore, gives the indices of pixels in `raster` that are equal to `x`.
- `np.any(arr)` returns True if and only if at least one element of `arr` evaluates to true. `np.any(raster == x)`, therefore, tells you whether or not at least one pixel of `raster` is x.

Assuming `fvc` and `toaRef_red` have the same shape and you want to create a new array `emiss` for emission, setting it to 0.99 if `fvc` is 1, to `0.979 - 0.046 * toaRef_red` if `fvc` is 0, to `0.971 * (1 - fvc) + 0.987 * fvc` if 0 < `fvc` < 1, and to NaN otherwise, you can do the following:

```
emiss = np.full(ndvi.shape, np.nan)    # create new array filled with nan
emiss[fvc == 1] = 0.99
mask = fvc == 0
emiss[mask] = 0.979 - 0.046 * toaRef_red[mask]
mask = (fvc > 0) & (fvc < 1)
emiss[mask] = 0.971 * (1 - fvc[mask]) + 0.987 * fvc[mask]
```

This is the same as:

```
emiss = np.full(ndvi.shape, np.nan)    # create new array filled with nan
emiss[np.where(fvc == 1)] = 0.99
idx = np.where(fvc == 0)
emiss[idx] = 0.979 - 0.046 * toaRef_red[idx]
idx = np.where((fvc > 0) & (fvc < 1))
emiss[idx] = 0.971 * (1 - fvc[idx]) + 0.987 * fvc[idx]
```

The latter is redundant, obviously. You don't need `np.where` here.